# Infra-Red Remote control on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, remote

I've just got a  new computer ([Fujitsi-Simens Amilo Xi 3670](http://uk.hardware.info/productinfo/83893/fujitsu-amilo-xi-3670#tab:specifications)). It came with a remote control for windows Vista. Is there any way to make it work with Ubuntu 14.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is:  (I have a Siemens too so both experiences should be similar)

When you do an `lsusb | grep --ignore-case infrared` you should receive output similar to this:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1934:0702 Feature Integration Technology Inc. (Fintek) 
Integrated Consumer Infrared Receiver/Transceiver
```

That is the host adapter for the remote control.

Then you should copy the [Remote Control Transceiver Configuration](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9898744/) into a file and save it for inclusion in the following step.

Then you should:

```
apt-get install lirc
```

to install the **L**inux **I**nfra-red **R**emote **C**ontrol support and when it asks you for a remote control file, browse to the file you've just saved above and it should be working out of the box now.

To show where the device is, do a: `ls /dev/lir*` and the output should show you the device.

To test it in VLC player, do the following:

- Open VLC player
- tools
- preferences
- show settings
- all
- go to interface - Control interfaces - Infrared
- enter the change configuration file the output of the `ls` command above in that field.

#### ... and enjoy your Infra-Red Remote Control! :-)